# why are we Instantiating an interface as 'ISudokuStrategy _simpleMarkupStrategy = new SimpleMarkUpStrategy(new SudokuMapper());'?

Tags: c#-4.0, interface

I can't find an appropriate answer in previous asked questions.
Below is a Unit Test code for my Sudoku-solver. In this app i have an interface 'ISudokuStrategy'. Only two classes inherits 'ISudokuStrategy': 'SimpleMarkUpStrategy' and 'NakedPairsStrategy'. My question is why are we Instantiating an interface as

```
private readonly ISudokuStrategy _simpleMarkupStrategy = new SimpleMarkUpStrategy(new SudokuMapper());
```

Why not

```
private readonly SimpleMarkUpStrategy _simpleMarkupStrategy = new SimpleMarkUpStrategy(new SudokuMapper());
```

here is my unit test

```
[TestClass]
public class SimpleMarkupStrategyTest
{
    private readonly ISudokuStrategy _simpleMarkupStrategy = new SimpleMarkUpStrategy(new SudokuMapper());

    [TestMethod]
    public void SimpleStrategyShouldSolveAlmostCompletedForTopLeftCell() 
    {
        int[,] sudokuBoard =
        {
            {0,1,2,3,9,8,4,7,5 },
            {5,3,8,4,1,7,6,2,9 },
            {4,7,9,5,6,2,3,1,8 },
            {9,6,7,2,8,4,1,5,3 },
            {3,8,4,6,5,1,7,9,2 },
            {2,5,1,7,3,9,8,6,4 },
            {8,2,5,1,4,6,9,3,7 },
            {1,9,3,8,7,5,2,4,6 },
            {7,4,6,9,2,3,5,8,1 }
        };

        var solvedSudokuBoard = _simpleMarkupStrategy.Solve(sudokuBoard);

        Assert.IsTrue(solvedSudokuBoard[0, 0] == 6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's you code, so... why do you? We cannot tell you why your code looks like it does.

What you *should* do, is make it a variable local to your unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class SimpleMarkupStrategyTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SimpleStrategyShouldSolveAlmostCompletedForTopLeftCell() 
    {
        var simpleMarkupStrategy = new SimpleMarkUpStrategy(new SudokuMapper());

        int[,] sudokuBoard =
        {
            {0,1,2,3,9,8,4,7,5 },
            {5,3,8,4,1,7,6,2,9 },
            {4,7,9,5,6,2,3,1,8 },
            {9,6,7,2,8,4,1,5,3 },
            {3,8,4,6,5,1,7,9,2 },
            {2,5,1,7,3,9,8,6,4 },
            {8,2,5,1,4,6,9,3,7 },
            {1,9,3,8,7,5,2,4,6 },
            {7,4,6,9,2,3,5,8,1 }
        };

        var solvedSudokuBoard = simpleMarkupStrategy.Solve(sudokuBoard);

        Assert.IsTrue(solvedSudokuBoard[0, 0] == 6);
    }
}
```

This way you cannot accidentally corrupt other unit tests, sharing a variable between them.

And as you can see, as a local variable, it even works with a `var` type and letting the compiler figure out what type it is.

One thing it does do, is making sure your class implements that interface. But I would assume that the whole program would not compile anyway, if you decided to remove that.

Comment: Thanks pal..I am learning, it's my 3rd month in C#. Much helpful.  @nvoigt